# Find the inverse function about a exponential related function

Tags: exponential-function, inverse

Here is the function:$$y = 4x + {x^m},where{\text{ 0 < m}} \leqslant {\text{1;}}$$
Approximately results is acceptable.

Comment: We can use a start of something like $x_0=\frac{y}{4.5}$ and use a couple of iterations of Newton's Method applied to the equation $4x+x^m-y=0$ to refine the estimate.

Comment: thank you for your answer, bu is there any closed form?

Comment: There is no closed form.  But the suggestion I made (and others like it) will give an approximate *formula*.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow   André Nicolas's suggestion and use Newton iteration scheme, starting from $x_{old}$, the new predicate $x_{new}$ will be given by $$x_{new}=\frac{(m-1) x_{old}^m+y}{m x_{old}^{m-1}+4}$$ Update $x_{old}$ by $x_{new}$ and repeat.

Taking into account the condition ${\text{ 0 < m}} \leqslant {\text{1}}$, you could start iterating at $$x_{old}=\frac{y}{4} \left(1-\frac{m}{5}\right) $$ which gives the exact solution at the boundaries of $m$.

Just for illustration purposes, suppose that we choose $m=0.12345$ and $y=9876$. The previous formula gives an estimate equal to $2408.04$ and the first iterate will be $2468.34$ which is the solution. If we change $m=0.56789$, the first estimate will be $2188.58$ and the successive iterates will be $2447.96$ and $2447.99$ which is the solution.

Comment: Thanks,but is there any close form?

Comment: @ChaoqingTang. A closed form could be possible for very specific values of $m$, I suppose. $0$ and $1$ are obvious, $1/2$,$1/3$, $1/4$ would be doable.

Comment: that's right, but m is a variable in another case of my work

Comment: So, no way I guess.